# kmeansとDoc2vecでクラスタリングした文章データのうち、特定のクラスタを呼び出したい

Tags: python

タイトルの通りです。
tsvファイルをpythonで読み込み、MeCabで分かち書きをしたのちにkmeans法でクラスタリングをすることには成功しています。
このクラスタリングによって得られた結果から、特定のクラスターの文章データを呼び出したいのですがうまくいきません。
当方、プログラミング初心者なためもしかしたら筋違いな質問かも知れませんが、どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

**使用環境

jupyter notebook

windows10**

ここから成功した部分

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument

import MeCab
import csv

mt = MeCab.Tagger()

reports = []
with open("インプットファイル",mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # インプットファイルには一行に文章ID,文章がtab区切りで保存されている
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for report_id, report in reader:
        words = []
        node = mt.parseToNode(report)
        while node:
            if len(node.surface) > 0:
                words.append(node.surface)
            node = node.next
        stopword = ['あれ','それ','これ']
        words2 = [token for token in words if token not in stopword]
        # wordsが文章の単語のリスト,tagsには文章IDを指定
        reports.append(TaggedDocument(words=words2, tags=[report_id]))
        print(words2)
```

```
model = Doc2Vec(documents=reports, size=128, window=8, min_count=2, workers=8)
model.save("allcomment_stop_doc2vec.model")
```

```
m = Doc2Vec.load("allcomment_stop_doc2vec.model")
```

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#ベクトルをリストに格納
vectors_list=[m.docvecs[n] for n in range(len(m.docvecs))]

#ドキュメント番号のリスト
doc_nums=range(1,1+len(m.docvecs))

#クラスタリング設定
n_clusters = 6
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, verbose=1, random_state=1, n_jobs=-1)

#クラスタリング実行
kmeans_model.fit(vectors_list)

#クラスタリングデータにラベル付け
labels=kmeans_model.labels_

#ラベルとドキュメント番号の辞書づくり
cluster_to_docs = defaultdict(list)
for cluster_id, doc_num in zip(labels, doc_nums):
    cluster_to_docs[cluster_id].append(doc_num)

#クラスター出力

for docs in cluster_to_docs.values():
    print(docs)
```

上記の出力結果(数値はtsvファイルに書かれている文章idに対応したものです)

```
[1, 6, 7, 9, 10, 17, 25, 35, 47, 104, 129, 131, 147, 150, 151, 152, 154, 155, 156, 157, 160, 162, 163, 164, 166, 168, 170, 171, 172, 174, 176, 177, 178, 180, 183, 191, 194, 199, 210, 219, 222, 233, 239, 240, 242, 253, 255, 256, 257, 268, 269, 272, 275, 294, 301, 303, 307, 311, 312, 314, 315, 320, 321, 322, 324, 330, 340, 347, 355, 357, 368, 369, 371, 373, 374, 376, 378, 380, 381, 385, 387, 405, 407, 409, 414, 417, 418, 419, 421, 427, 431, 432, 433, 436, 439, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 455, 458, 459, 460, 463, 465, 466, 468, 471, 490, 493, 500, 507, 536, 552, 565, 566, 568, 573, 575, 577, 579, 581, 583, 596, 604, 611, 612, 618, 619, 625, 630, 634, 640, 644, 646, 648, 649, 654, 655, 663, 667, 668, 670, 675, 681, 682, 684, 685, 687, 695, 696, 697, 698, 702, 703, 708, 710, 711, 736, 755, 762, 763, 766, 771, 779, 791, 799, 807, 810, 813, 814, 817, 824, 829, 842, 843, 847, 856, 860, 870, 879, 889, 894, 895, 897, 904, 911, 919, 920, 922, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 936, 937, 949, 951, 952, 956, 957, 958, 959, 962, 963, 965, 968, 979, 985, 989, 996, 997, 999]
[2, 11, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 30, 34, 36, 38, 43, 45, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 114, 116, 121, 123, 124, 126, 127, 128, 130, 132, 134, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 153, 159, 167, 193, 200, 201, 204, 205, 206, 209, 211, 212, 214, 215, 217, 218, 224, 225, 234, 235, 238, 241, 243, 249, 250, 251, 254, 258, 259, 264, 266, 270, 271, 276, 277, 278, 279, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 345, 346, 349, 350, 353, 359, 360, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 370, 372, 377, 379, 423, 424, 425, 449, 451, 452, 453, 454, 469, 475, 477, 479, 481, 483, 486, 494, 502, 506, 510, 511, 513, 514, 516, 523, 526, 527, 528, 530, 531, 532, 533, 537, 541, 544, 547, 548, 551, 555, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 584, 585, 586, 588, 590, 591, 593, 594, 595, 598, 600, 601, 605, 606, 617, 636, 645, 669, 689, 705, 706, 712, 714, 715, 716, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 731, 732, 733, 734, 738, 739, 741, 742, 744, 745, 747, 749, 751, 752, 754, 758, 760, 761, 764, 765, 767, 768, 769, 770, 773, 774, 775, 776, 781, 783, 785, 787, 789, 790, 794, 796, 802, 803, 812, 815, 816, 819, 825, 832, 848, 853, 855, 857, 861, 862, 864, 865, 866, 869, 871, 872, 873, 876, 888, 898, 899, 900, 905, 906, 907, 909, 915, 917, 938, 940, 943, 948, 964, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1020, 1022, 1023, 1025, 1026, 1028, 1030, 1033, 1034, 1035]
[3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 24, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46, 48, 49, 56, 59, 62, 66, 93, 112, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 122, 125, 133, 135, 136, 146, 149, 158, 161, 165, 173, 179, 185, 202, 203, 207, 208, 213, 216, 220, 221, 223, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 236, 237, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 252, 261, 262, 263, 265, 267, 273, 274, 280, 342, 343, 344, 348, 351, 352, 356, 358, 361, 362, 382, 384, 386, 388, 404, 406, 408, 410, 411, 412, 413, 415, 416, 420, 422, 426, 428, 429, 434, 435, 437, 438, 450, 456, 462, 464, 467, 472, 473, 474, 476, 478, 480, 482, 484, 485, 487, 488, 489, 491, 492, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 501, 503, 504, 505, 508, 509, 512, 515, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 524, 525, 529, 534, 535, 538, 539, 540, 542, 545, 546, 549, 550, 553, 554, 556, 557, 563, 564, 569, 578, 582, 587, 589, 592, 597, 599, 602, 607, 613, 614, 616, 624, 651, 657, 658, 660, 661, 662, 671, 672, 674, 678, 686, 688, 694, 699, 707, 713, 717, 718, 719, 720, 730, 735, 737, 740, 743, 746, 748, 750, 753, 756, 757, 759, 772, 777, 778, 780, 782, 784, 786, 788, 792, 793, 795, 797, 798, 800, 801, 804, 805, 806, 808, 809, 811, 818, 823, 826, 827, 828, 830, 831, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 844, 845, 846, 849, 850, 851, 852, 854, 858, 859, 863, 867, 868, 874, 875, 877, 878, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 890, 891, 892, 893, 896, 901, 902, 903, 908, 910, 912, 913, 914, 916, 941, 942, 944, 946, 947, 950, 953, 954, 960, 961, 966, 967, 994, 995, 1009, 1014, 1019, 1021, 1024, 1027, 1029, 1031, 1032, 1036, 1037]
[15, 16, 148, 169, 175, 181, 182, 184, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 192, 195, 196, 197, 198, 260, 292, 295, 296, 297, 299, 300, 304, 306, 309, 310, 313, 316, 317, 327, 332, 337, 338, 339, 354, 375, 383, 389, 400, 430, 440, 441, 457, 461, 470, 567, 570, 574, 580, 603, 609, 610, 615, 620, 622, 623, 626, 627, 628, 629, 631, 632, 633, 635, 638, 647, 650, 652, 653, 656, 659, 673, 676, 677, 679, 680, 690, 691, 693, 700, 709, 918, 921, 923, 929, 935, 939, 945, 955, 969, 971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 986, 987, 988, 990, 991, 992, 993, 998]
[293, 298, 302, 305, 308, 318, 319, 323, 325, 326, 328, 329, 331, 333, 334, 335, 341, 390, 391, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 401, 402, 403, 543, 571, 572, 576, 608, 621, 637, 639, 641, 642, 643, 692, 701, 704, 820, 821, 822, 970]
[336, 392, 393, 394, 664, 665, 666, 683]
[222, 331, 317, 114, 45, 8] range(0, 6) 194, 199, 210, 219, 222, 233, 239, 240, 242, 253, 255, 256, 257, 268, 269, 272, 275, 294, 301, 303, 307, 311, 312, 314, 315, 320, 321, 322, 324, 330, 340, 347, 355, 357, 368, 369, 371, 373, 374, 376, 378, 380, 381, 385, 387, 405, 407, 409, 414, 417, 418, 419, 421, 427, 431, 432, 433, 436, 439, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 455, 458, 459, 460, 463, 465, 466, 468, 471, 490, 493, 500, 507, 536, 552, 565, 566, 568, 573, 575, 577, 579, 581, 583, 596, 604, 611, 612, 618, 619, 625, 630, 634, 640, 644, 646, 648, 649, 654, 655, 663, 667, 668, 670, 675, 681, 682, 684, 685, 687, 695, 696, 697, 698, 702, 703, 708, 710, 711, 736, 755, 762, 763, 766, 771, 779, 791, 799, 807, 810, 813, 814, 817, 824, 829, 842, 843, 847, 856, 860, 870, 879, 889, 894, 895, 897, 904, 911, 919, 920, 922, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 936, 937, 949, 951, 952, 956, 957, 958, 959, 962, 963, 965, 968, 979, 985, 989, 996, 997, 999]
[2, 11, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 30, 34, 36, 38, 43, 45, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 114, 116, 121, 123, 124, 126, 127, 128, 130, 132, 134, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 153, 159, 167, 193, 200, 201, 204, 205, 206, 209, 211, 212, 214, 215, 217, 218, 224, 225, 234, 235, 238, 241, 243, 249, 250, 251, 254, 258, 259, 264, 266, 270, 271, 276, 277, 278, 279, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 345, 346, 349, 350, 353, 359, 360, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 370, 372, 377, 379, 423, 424, 425, 449, 451, 452, 453, 454, 469, 475, 477, 479, 481, 483, 486, 494, 502, 506, 510, 511, 513, 514, 516, 523, 526, 527, 528, 530, 531, 532, 533, 537, 541, 544, 547, 548, 551, 555, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 584, 585, 586, 588, 590, 591, 593, 594, 595, 598, 600, 601, 605, 606, 617, 636, 645, 669, 689, 705, 706, 712, 714, 715, 716, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 731, 732, 733, 734, 738, 739, 741, 742, 744, 745, 747, 749, 751, 752, 754, 758, 760, 761, 764, 765, 767, 768, 769, 770, 773, 774, 775, 776, 781, 783, 785, 787, 789, 790, 794, 796, 802, 803, 812, 815, 816, 819, 825, 832, 848, 853, 855, 857, 861, 862, 864, 865, 866, 869, 871, 872, 873, 876, 888, 898, 899, 900, 905, 906, 907, 909, 915, 917, 938, 940, 943, 948, 964, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1020, 1022, 1023, 1025, 1026, 1028, 1030, 1033, 1034, 1035]
[3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 24, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46, 48, 49, 56, 59, 62, 66, 93, 112, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 122, 125, 133, 135, 136, 146, 149, 158, 161, 165, 173, 179, 185, 202, 203, 207, 208, 213, 216, 220, 221, 223, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 236, 237, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 252, 261, 262, 263, 265, 267, 273, 274, 280, 342, 343, 344, 348, 351, 352, 356, 358, 361, 362, 382, 384, 386, 388, 404, 406, 408, 410, 411, 412, 413, 415, 416, 420, 422, 426, 428, 429, 434, 435, 437, 438, 450, 456, 462, 464, 467, 472, 473, 474, 476, 478, 480, 482, 484, 485, 487, 488, 489, 491, 492, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 501, 503, 504, 505, 508, 509, 512, 515, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 524, 525, 529, 534, 535, 538, 539, 540, 542, 545, 546, 549, 550, 553, 554, 556, 557, 563, 564, 569, 578, 582, 587, 589, 592, 597, 599, 602, 607, 613, 614, 616, 624, 651, 657, 658, 660, 661, 662, 671, 672, 674, 678, 686, 688, 694, 699, 707, 713, 717, 718, 719, 720, 730, 735, 737, 740, 743, 746, 748, 750, 753, 756, 757, 759, 772, 777, 778, 780, 782, 784, 786, 788, 792, 793, 795, 797, 798, 800, 801, 804, 805, 806, 808, 809, 811, 818, 823, 826, 827, 828, 830, 831, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 844, 845, 846, 849, 850, 851, 852, 854, 858, 859, 863, 867, 868, 874, 875, 877, 878, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 890, 891, 892, 893, 896, 901, 902, 903, 908, 910, 912, 913, 914, 916, 941, 942, 944, 946, 947, 950, 953, 954, 960, 961, 966, 967, 994, 995, 1009, 1014, 1019, 1021, 1024, 1027, 1029, 1031, 1032, 1036, 1037]
[15, 16, 148, 169, 175, 181, 182, 184, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 192, 195, 196, 197, 198, 260, 292, 295, 296, 297, 299, 300, 304, 306, 309, 310, 313, 316, 317, 327, 332, 337, 338, 339, 354, 375, 383, 389, 400, 430, 440, 441, 457, 461, 470, 567, 570, 574, 580, 603, 609, 610, 615, 620, 622, 623, 626, 627, 628, 629, 631, 632, 633, 635, 638, 647, 650, 652, 653, 656, 659, 673, 676, 677, 679, 680, 690, 691, 693, 700, 709, 918, 921, 923, 929, 935, 939, 945, 955, 969, 971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 986, 987, 988, 990, 991, 992, 993, 998]
[293, 298, 302, 305, 308, 318, 319, 323, 325, 326, 328, 329, 331, 333, 334, 335, 341, 390, 391, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 401, 402, 403, 543, 571, 572, 576, 608, 621, 637, 639, 641, 642, 643, 692, 701, 704, 820, 821, 822, 970]
[336, 392, 393, 394, 664, 665, 666, 683]
[222, 331, 317, 114, 45, 8]
```

ここまでは成功した部分です。
ここで、最初のクラスタの文章データを呼び出そうと

```
print(reports[1, 6, 7, 9,~,999])
```

とすると

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

となり複数の引数を渡すことができません。
解決策をどなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: `print(list(map(reports.__getitem__, (1, 6, 7, 9, 999))))` など。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。無事クラスタ内のデータを呼び出すことができました。
上記のコードですと文章データとタグが同時に呼び出されるのですが、文章データのみを呼び出す方法などはありますでしょうか

Comment: TaggedDocument の構造がよく分かりませんので、確かな事は言えないのですが、`print([reports[i].words for i in (1, 6, 7, 9, 999)])` でしょうか。

Comment: 出来ました！！！！
本当に助かります、ありがとうございます！

Comment: @metropolis コメントではなく回答にされては。

Comment: ベストアンサーにできないのはそういう理屈だったのですね、調べても出てこず困っていました笑

Comment: @jumpeimanai 自己回答も推奨されているので、良かったらご検討ください。時間が経てば自分で回答の承認もできます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(list(map(reports.__getitem__, (1, 6, 7, 9, 999))))` など。

文章データのみを呼び出すには、TaggedDocument の構造がよく分かりませんので、確かな事は言えないのですが、`print([reports[i].words for i in (1, 6, 7, 9, 999)])` でしょうか。

<sub>-- この回答は、[metropolis さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)のコメントを元にコミュニティ wiki として投稿するものです。</sub>